# Insert a dot at a certain point on a line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to know how to insert a dot (or some kind of marker) at a distinct point on a curve/line in matplotlib. Using the tutorial documentation, http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

we plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16])
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, I know how to transform this line into a series of points, here using red dots `'ro'`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I add a "dot" at a distinct point? For example, add a dot at point `[3,9]`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call `plt.plot(x, y, 'style')` again, like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro') # Your original list
plt.plot(5, 25, 'go')                 # Additional point
plt.plot(6, 36, 'yo')                 # Additional point
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 40])              # Modified axis
plt.show()
```

[image: Result of running the program]

Comment: I get the feeling ShanZhengYang wanted to plot the original list as a line and overlay the dots. (simply remove the `'ro'` part in line 2)